Spring Boot 3.4.0: ConverterNotFoundException for SpEL property spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.producer.routing-key-expression
After upgrading my application from Spring Boot 3.3.X to 3.4.0 (Spring Cloud 2024.0.0) I get the following Exception at startup:
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.producer.routing-key-expression' to org.springframework.expression.Expression:

    Property: spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.producer.routing-key-expression
    Value: "'response.'+headers.get("tenant")"
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties] - 62:72
    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.expression.Expression]

In my application.properties I have this line:
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.producer.routing-key-expression='response.'+headers.get("tenant")
This worked fine in Spring Boot 3.3.X with Spring Cloud 2023.0.X
I tried the combination Spring Boot 3.4.0 with Spring Cloud 2023.0.X (using spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false) but the Exception still occurs.
